# Python multiline lambda

Tags: c#, python, lambda

I am wondering if there is possible to find some equivalent to C# multiline lambda function in Python.

Let's say, that I have C# code like this:
[image]

I want to write some equivalent python code for this method. But as far as I know there is no possibility to have multiline lambda functions in python. Any ideas about some python equivalent code for this?

Comment: Even if there was a way, what would be a good reason for using it? You are already defining a name for that function (`func`) and already using multi-lines, why not use a standard `def`? Also, Python lambdas are only allowed to contain expressions (there goes the 'if')

Comment: In this specific case it can be rewritten as a one-line in C# or Python `(t1,t2) => t1 <= t2 ? t2 - t1 : t1 * t2`.

Comment: @DeepSpace One reason is scope: It might not be desirable to make a function more accessible than necessary. Nested functions could be used, but even these could be called again (in the current scope), which might not be desired.

Comment: @DeepSpace That is beside the point I am conveying - Intent of use can be communicated or enforced by software design, even at this level of abstraction.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can define your lambda on multiple lines if you put the expression in parentheses. This creates an implied line continuation, causing newlines to be ignored up to the closing parenthesis.

```
>>> func = lambda a,b: (
...     b - a if a <= b else
...     a*b
... )
>>>
>>> func(23, 42)
19
```

You can also explicitly use the line continuation character "\", but this is not the approach preferred by the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length). (Not that binding lambdas to names are [a good idea to begin with](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), in fairness...)

```
>>> func = lambda a,b: \
...     b - a if a <= b else \
...     a*b
>>>
>>> func(23, 42)
19
```

Of course, you can only have expressions inside your lambda, and not statements. So proper `if` blocks and `return`s and the like are still impossible.

---

Additionally, it may not be necessary to use lambdas here at all, because unlike C# (prior to the recent v. 7.0), Python is capable of nesting full functions:

```
>>> def method(x,y):
...     def func(a,b):
...             if a <= b:
...                     return b - a
...             return a * b
...     return func(x,y)
...
>>> method(23, 42)
19
```

Comment: Actually I think C# 7's local functions might act like Python nested functions.

Comment: @juharr, oh, nice. I'm looking forward to using them :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a tricky way of creating not just a multi-line lambda for formatting, but also one that is truly multi-line logically. It involves using the exec command to turn a string into a function. I don't know how efficient this is but it works. I came up with this because sometimes I want to create a custom lambda function for the sorted function and don't want to define a persistent function. So check out the following:

```
def strToFun(x):
    name = x[x.find(' ') + 1:x.find('(')]
    exec(x)
    ret = eval(name)
    return ret
```

This will create a function and return a pointer to that function. If you run the following test, you will see there is a function called f1 but not one called fun1. The fun1 is a placeholder because we have to have a function name when using def. exec creates a function inside the strToFun function. eval returns a pointer to that function without executing it. The function returns the pointer and the inner function called fun1 falls out of scope.

```
f1 = strToFun('def fun1(x): return x + 1')
print(f1, type(f1), f1(100))
print(dir())
```

Instead of storing the newly created function to a variable you could also just use it directly just like you would a lambda expression:

```
print(strToFun('def fun1(x): return x + 1')(200))
```

So I use it like this to create complex lambdas when I need to:

```
countries = ['Uganda', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Albania', 'USA']

print(sorted(countries
, key = strToFun(
'''def _fun1(x):
   if x == 'USA':
      return (0,)
   elif x == 'Canada':
      return (1,)
   else:
      return(2, x)
   ''')))
```

I am sure I will get a lot of comments about how unpythonic this is and that if Guido wanted us to have multi-line lambdas he would have put it in the language. Nevertheless, it is an interesting and effective trick when you need it, so what could be wrong with that?

Comment: Yes it is unpythonic. Yes Guido is rolling over .. oh wait he's still kicking around somewhere and yet .. yes I like this and will use it

Answer (score 3):

You can write it as an inline function:

```
lambda x, y : (x<=y)*(y-x) + (x>y)*x*y
```

Comment: That takes me back to the days of ancient BASIC dialects, where that sort of construct was common. Although we did it slightly differently, since comparisons returned -1 for true.

Answer (score 2):

No reason to use a lambda if you need multilines, instead use a scoped function definition. Since it is defined inside the method it is only visible inside that context.

```
def Method(x, y):
   def func(temp1, temp2):
       if temp1 <= temp2:
           return temp2 - temp1
       else:
           return temp1 * temp2

   return func(temp1, temp2)
```

I say anytime you are tempted to give a lambda a name, except as something that was passed to you from another place, use def instead of lambda.

Comment: But then we have to _find_ that function.  Other languages `javascript`, `kotlin`, `R` etc allow multi-line anonymous functions/lambdas to be inlined and so we can read chained functions  left to right without needing to go rooting around for wherever that `def` might be. In this case it may be close to the logic - but what about inside a 125 line method (pls don't say to break up that method - there are times that is needed)

Comment: The def can be scoped inside the function, just like the lambda. `a = lambda x: x + 2` can literally  be replaced with `def a(x): return x + 2` right there on the same line of code.

Comment: That is true  . It is however still distracting / tiring to go jumping around  even if within the same function instead of just reading it left to right with languages that have  support for lambdas that are fully baked functions (instead of the "no statements" and "one line" restrictions).   That and also we need to apply the lambda first and the data second and finally we need to do `list(blah)` since in python3 everything's generators.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to play with it a little and ultimately ended up with this:

```
def lambdas(x):
   if not x.startswith('('):
      # if the parameters are not enclosed in parentheses, supply them automatically
      i = x.find(':')
      x = 'def _func({0}):{1}'.format(x[:i], x[i+1:])
   else:
      x = 'def _func' + x
   exec(x)
   ret = eval('_func')
   return ret
```

I settled on the name `lambdas` because it looks like `lambda` but the `s` at the end for string. I also decided it made sense to skip the name and just go straight for the parameter list which does need to be in parentheses though.

```
data = ['Uganda', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Albania', 'USA']
print(sorted(data, 
key = lambdas(
'''(x):
   if x == 'USA':
      return (0,)
   elif x == 'Canada':
      return (1,)
   else:
      return(2, x)
   ''')))
```

or

```
print(sorted(data, 
key = lambdas(
'''x:
   if x == 'USA':
      return (0,)
   elif x == 'Canada':
      return (1,)
   else:
      return(2, x)
   ''')))
```